# Python: How to Replicate a Replicated List Without Cloning

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I enter `t=[[False]*2]*2`, I get the list `[[False, False], [False, False]]`. But when I enter `t[0][0] = True`, `t[1][0]` also changes to `True`, leaving me with `[[True, False], [True, False]]`. I only want `[[True, False], [False, False]]`. As a second option, I could assign `t=[[False]*2, [False]*2]` and then changing `t[0][0] = True` gets me what I want (`[[True, False], [False, False]]`), but my real list is a lot bigger than that, so I would rather not use option 2. I figured that this was a similar issue to cloning versus copying with lists, so I tried:
`([[False]*2])*2`

`([False]*2)*2`

`[[False]*2][:]*2`

`t = [False]*2
t = t*2`

`list([False]*2)*2`

`list([[False]*2])*2`

`[list([False]*2)]*2`. None of these worked. Is there any way to do this without importing any package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you build your lists using list comprehension, each list object will point to a unique address, rather than share the same reference.

```
t = [[False for x in range(2)] for y in range(2)]
t[0][0] = True
t  # [[True, False], [False, False]]
```

Comment: Of course! I used list comprehension everywhere else but I forgot to use it here. By the way, `xrange` does not work in Python 3 (it's just `range`.) Is there really no way to do this without list comprehension though?

Comment: @P.Gordy There's also `itertools.repeat(val, numberoftimes)`, however the list comprehension will be faster. And if you nest the `repeat` then it's getting ugly really fast.

Comment: The `[False for x in range(2)]` can actually just be `[False]*2`. Only the second one needs to have the `for y in range(2)`.